# Swift : Define a closure compatible with Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c, swift

I tried to declare a closure matching the following Objective-C block:

```
typedef void(^TyphoonDefinitionBlock)(TyphoonDefinition *definition);
```

like this:

```
var config: TyphoonDefinitionBlock = { (definition: TyphoonDefinition) in
    definition.injectProperty("quest", with: nil)
}
```

. . .  and got the following error. (see image).

[image]

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Apart from Apple employees we're ALL new to Swift development. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare `definition` as an [ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1014) (`TyphoonDefinition!`) because in objective-C it is a pointer that can be nil.

Normal variables (and constants) in swift cannot be nil. They must contain a value.

Comment: @JasperBlues haha no worries. I'll also just say that we are all fairly new to Swift since it was announced less than a week ago ;) And we are all just now diving into the details of the language and figuring things out that seem obvious in retrospect

Answer (score 1):

I'm using typealias, taken from http://berzniz.com/post/87924122326/notes-from-coding-in-swift
    typealias resultBlock = (success: Bool, result: AnyObject!) -> Void

Answer (score 1):

Like to explain it in details,start with your piece of code

Objective C 
    `typedef void(^TyphoonDefinitionBlock)(TyphoonDefinition *definition);`

In Swift you make it like this
    `typealias TyphoonDefinitionBlock = (definition:TyphoonDefinition?)->Void`

If you want to intimate to caller object after particular moment you need to make a property.
    `var typhoonDefinitionCompletion:BlockTyphoonDefinitionBlock?`

you can use `typhoonDefinitionCompletion`and you can raise the callback message like this.
     `self.typhoonDefinitionCompletion!(definition:passyourtyphoneDefinition)`